# External API Calls server or client side?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently working on an analytics webapp with a react frontend and node (express) backend.
Describing the functionality in a nutshell:

A user will be able to login on the website, search for a YouTube username and then the YouTube API is called, the data will be stored in a mysql db via my express API and also the data will be used to calucalte some statistics which afterwards are displayed in a dashboard.

Now I was wondering if I should:

1. Call the YouTube API from the frontend, i.e. inside my react code, do the calculations display them and and then store it in the DB via my express API.
2. Or, from the react app call an endpoint in my express API that will then call the YouTube API, store the data in the DB and then pass on the data to my react app.

Are there any best practices or up-/downsides to either approach?

Comment: I would prefer to send them all fromthe backend, as this makes the frontend transparent to what's happening really. But most important, it prevents to expose your API key and other private details to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When answering questions like these, it's important to remember that the client-side is different for each and every user that visits your website, their internet speed, their GPU & CPU power, etc., but the server is most commonly held in a stable container and much more powerful than a client.

The proper way would be the following:

#### 1. Obtain a search query from a client

Meaning you should get the user's search query from an input, or any other form of control (text area, checkbox, etc.), this way client is doing the least business logic, as it should. The client should always focus more on UI / UX rather than business logic.

#### 2. Send query to the server

Let the server use the query you've just obtained from client, call the youtube api from the server (either explicitly using Axios, or find a node.js youtube library), and do all the necessary calculation on the backend

#### 3. Send processed data to the client

Let client receive the data in the form which is ready for use (iterations, mappings, etc.) - again separating concerns, server - business logic, client - UI / UX

Now to be fair, the example you have will most commonly be done all on the client-side, since it is not as computationally heavy as other enterprise examples, but this is a good rule to follow for big projects, and no one would really complain if you did it this way, since it would be the proper way.